# Unique Combination Frequency

Tags: sql, excel, r

I have a dataset with 10 columns. The first column is an unique identifier. The 9 other columns are related attributes. For now, let's just say they are integers. If needed, the data could easily be pivoted to a key-value.

Ex:

```
id|attr1|attr2|attr3|...
a |  2  |  5  |  7  |...
b |  3  |  1  |null |...
c |  2  |null |null |...
d |  1  |  2  |  5  |...
e |  2  |  1  |  3  |...
```

I'm essentially looking for the most frequent combinations of any length with at least a pair. So my output for this would be:

```
unq   | frequency
1,2   | 2
1,3   | 2
1,5   | 1
2,3   | 1
2,5   | 2
2,7   | 1
1,2,3 | 1
1,2,5 | 1
2,5,7 | 1
```

(did this manually - so hopefully there are no errors) - the order of the paring doesn't matter. `2,5,7 = 5,2,7 = 7,5,2 etc.`

Any thoughts? I am open to different tools. I have access to R, excel, sql server, mysql, etc.

`Excel` is preferred but not required!

Comment: How many attributes are there and what is the range of values an attribute can take on? A naive algorithm might not scale, and I don't know if there is any tractable algorithm (but I am not an expert on that)

Comment: Can you explain how you get from your dataset to your answer? I'm struggling to make sense of "most frequent combinations of any length with at least a pair".

Comment: Got some better info. It can have 1 to 9 attributes. @Richie - Basically for Row D - here are all the unique combinations for that row (semicolon delimited): 
`1
2
5
1,2
1,5
2,5
1,2,5 ` 
So the only ones that qualify as "at least a pair" are 
`1,2
1,5
2,5
1,2,5`

Does that help? Please feel free to ask again if it doesn't. I want to be clear in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution in R:

Recreate the data

```
x <- data.frame(
    id = letters[1:5],
    attr1 = c(2,3,2,1,2),
    attr2 = c(5,1,NA,2,1),
    attr3 = c(7,NA,NA,5,3))
x

  id attr1 attr2 attr3
1  a     2     5     7
2  b     3     1    NA
3  c     2    NA    NA
4  d     1     2     5
5  e     2     1     3
```

Create a function to list all the combinations

```
make_combinations <- function(data, size){
  t1 <- apply(data[, -1], 1, function(data)unname(sort(data)))
  t2 <- lapply(t1, function(xt){if(length(xt)>=size){combn(xt, size)}})
  t3 <- sapply(t2[!is.na(t2)], 
      function(chunk){if(!is.null(chunk))apply(chunk, 2, function(x)paste(x, collapse=","))})
  t4 <- unlist(t3)
  t4
}
```

Create a second function to count the combinations

```
count_combinations <- function(data, nn=2:3){
  tmp <- unlist(lapply(nn, function(n)make_combinations(data, n)))
  sort(table(tmp), decreasing=TRUE)
}
```

The results:

```
count_combinations(x, 2:3)


  1,2   1,3   2,5 1,2,3 1,2,5   1,5   2,3 2,5,7   2,7   5,7 
    2     2     2     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

Comment: I got `Error in apply(x[, -1], 1, function(data) unname(sort(data))) : 
  object 'x' not found` I am VERY new to R so perhaps I did something wrong?

Comment: No, my mistake.  I have edited the question.  There still was an `x` lurking in the function that should have referred to `data`.  Please try again.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry.  But it's Friday night.  I should have done real work, and I need to go spend some time with my other half.  To reverse engineer, may I suggest you include print statements in the code to print t1, t2, t3 and t4.  That should make it reasonably clear what's happening in the workings.

Comment: Dude you rock - that totally worked. First time using R and I am impressed. IF you or anybody else could tell me how I could translate this output into a two column table, that would be awesome, but this is fantastic!

Comment: `combs <- count_combinations(x, 2:3)`, then `data.frame(Combs = names(combs), Count = combs)` should get you two columns.

Comment: `as.data.frame(count_combinations(x, 2:3))` is another option. Actually, I guess this will return a data.frame with 1 column and a `rownames()` attribute associated with it.

Comment: Just in case anyone else comes along via search, I skipped the first part above, created the two functions (just copy/paste), imported my csv `rawsku <- read.table("rawsku.csv",header=T,sep=",")`, made sure it looked right `names(rawsku)`; `head(rawsku)` and then run `rawsku_results <- count_combinations(rawsku,2:9)` the 2:9 looks for groupings between 2 and 9, then write it out to csv: `write.csv(rawsku_results,file="rawsku_results.csv")`

Answer (score 2):

Here's your data, without the `id` column.

```
dfr <- data.frame(
  attr1 = c(2,3,2,1,2), 
  attr2 = c(5,1,NA,2,1), 
  attr3 = c(7,NA,NA,5,3)
)
```

This retrieves all the combinations, but the output form takes a little bit of navigating.

```
lapply(
  seq_len(nrow(dfr)),              #loop over rows
  function(row) 
  {
    lapply(
      seq_along(dfr)[-1],          #loop over lengths of combination, -1 is to ignore singletons
      function(m) 
      {
        combn(dfr[row, ], m)
      }
    )
  }
)
```